# How to make the "slider thumb" on a range slider go outside of the track

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical range slider and I want the "thumb" (the thing you move on the slider) to be wider than the track itself (very similar to how the android sliders look).

I've tried a lot of stuff and this is the closest I managed to be

This is my code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="sliderContainer">
   <input type="range">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(window).on("load resize", function () {
   var sliderWidth = $('[type=range]').width();

   $('.custom-style-element-related-to-range').remove();

   $('<style class="custom-style-element-related-to-range">input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb { box-shadow: -' + sliderWidth + 'px 0 0 ' + sliderWidth + 'px;}<style/>').appendTo('head');
});
```

CSS

```
.sliderContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: -27px;
    top: 127px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 135px;
}

input[type='range'] {
    width: 120px;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type='range'] {
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-color: #D2CECC;
        transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        height: 3px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        color: #0098A6;
    }
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        width: 10px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #434343;
        color: #0098A6;
        border: 10px #0098A6;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: -3px;
    }
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background-color: #0098A6;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    background-color: #D2CECC;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: #0098A6;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background-color: #D2CECC;
}
```

Any idea on how to progress would be great

EDIT:

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Objective]

I've tried some more stuff and managed to make it so the thumb is "outside" but now the track doesnt change color.

CSS

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type='range'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-color: #D2CECC;
        transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        height: 3px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        color: #0098A6;
    }
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        width: 10px;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        height: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #0098A6;
        color: transparent;
        border: 10px #0098A6;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-top: -3px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609481/trouble-styling-range-input-thumb

Comment: Not exactly, since I need the "filled" part to change color and that is what is giving me trouble, since I cant manage to make it fill and keep the thumb outside

Comment: @LuisFernandez Please see my updated code and answer. This should meet your requirements now.

Comment: Can you create a working example that help us understanding a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We all know and love CSS only solutions. However, sometimes it just isn't the best solution! It is often less readable, includes a lot of workarounds and is limited to the boundaries of CSS.

I really like [@AlexioVay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2829128/alexiovay)'s approach and solution, but it has an issue where the colored part only updates, if you let go of the handle, due to CSS limitations, (**Edit:** fixed now) and you will probably have a bad time customizing it to the deepest of your needs. Since you are using jQuery already, why not just use the jQuery UI?

I think this solution is **much, much** more readable and practical.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    value: 35,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  });
});
```

```css
#slider {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  border: 0;
  width: 3px;
}

#slider * {
  outline: none;
}

#slider .ui-slider-range,
#slider .ui-slider-handle {
  background: #0098A6;
  border: 0;
}

#slider .ui-slider-handle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

Easy to read [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) and easy to customize. Since it isn't just a default HTML slider, you can target each item individually for future event-listeners or custom CSS. This way it is not limited to the CSS limits.

So, yes, my solution isn't CSS, but in my opinion the better one and much more practical.

Comment: When I tried your code in my project I can click on the track to change the values but i cant drag the thumb and I can't figure out how could this happen since the snippet works perfectly. Do you have any clue as of why could this be happening?

Comment: Take a look at the developer console inside your browser. Does it say anything?

Comment: Not a single message related to the issue no. One thing I've noticed is that when I click AND release the thumb it adds the ui-state-hover class to it. Should't it be added as soon as I click (before releasing) so it can be moved?. I'm not familiar with jqueryui so I'm assuming ui-state-hover is the one that handles displacement.

Comment: Try your to implement my snippet again. I added one small source (_524 bytes_) as jQuery UI doesn't support touch and mobile devices by default. This should work now.

Comment: Sorry, I took the day off yesterday. It works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have spent some time to solve this since it is tricky to find the best solution.

The `overflow: hidden` on `input[type='range']` prevents that your range thumb is "outside" of the range slider.

You could use `box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px #0098A6;` on `input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb` to have a css tricky way to show the range background color, but this also 
 again requires `overflow: hidden` on the range track and would again prevent showing your range thumb outside (I have commented this part out in my solution).

So I managed to solve this with a JS/JQuery solution. You would also need to specify `min` and `max` attributes on the HTML part in order to let JS read those values when dragging the range slider.

You can just watch the CodePen that I have created for this issue and copy the parts to your needs. It also demonstrates that it works:

https://codepen.io/alexiovay/pen/VwYMZpg

I sticked to your desired design outcome as much as I could.

Comment: @LuisFernandez *[12:48 Update]: Changed the JS code that fixes that the range track background color changes after dragging the range thumb.*

Comment: Good (almost) CSS only solution. +1